# Problem with TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key

Tags: python, typeerror

I had issues with this line in the below code, which throws

```
TypeError: Cannot index by location index with a non-integer key
```

How to change the code?

```
exit_price = df.loc[exit_time + dt.timedelta(minutes=1)].Open
```

---

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

asset = "TSLA"
intraday = yf.download(asset, start = "2021-03-17", end = "2021-03-18", interval = "1m")

def Intradaytrend(df, entry, exit):
    ret_120min = df.iloc[120].Open/df.iloc[0].Open -1
    tickret = df.Open.pct_change()
    if ret_120min > entry:
        buyprice = df.iloc[121].Open
        buytime = df.iloc[121].name
        cumulated = (tickret.loc[buytime:] +1).cumprod() -1
        exittime = cumulated[(cumulated < -exit) | (cumulated > exit)].first_valid_index()
        if exittime == None:
            exitprice = df.iloc[-1].Open
        else:
            exitprice = df.iloc[exittime + dt.timedelta(minutes=1)].Open
        profit = exitprice - buyprice
        profitrel = profit/buyprice
        return profitrel
    else:
        return None 


Intradaytrend(intraday, 0.01, 0.01)
```

Comment: first you could use `type()` to check what type of data you have in `exit_time` and `dt.timedelta(minutes=1)` - `print( type(exit_time), type(dt.timedelta(minutes=1)), type(exit_time+dt.timedelta(minutes=1))` . It seems you have values which are not integer numbers - and probably you will have to convert them to integers. So first use `print()` to debug code.

Comment: you show `loc[...]` in like which makes problem (which can works with names) but in full code you use `iloc[...]` which needs integers. Maybe you simply need `loc` instead `iloc`. OR maybe when you use `exit_time` then you have to filter by some other column instead of indexes - ie `df[ df["time"] < exittime + dt.timedelta(minutes=1) ]`